# Alexa - Exclude specific word form slot / utterance

Tags: speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having an issue with Alexa failing to accurately recognise an AMAZON.YesIntent.

The problem is that I have a separate intent where the user supplies a single character in answer to a question (i.e. options from a list).  This has a custom slot type "ALPHANUMERIC", which only contains the characters "a.|b." etc.  The utterances look like this:

```
SelectionIntent my choice is {Alpha_selection}
SelectionIntent {Alpha_selection}
```

When I say "Yes" in an environment with even slight background noise, Alexa almost always picks my own `SelectionIntent` and provides the value "Yes" in the `{Alpha_selection}` slot.

While I could change my back-end code so that it copes with getting a "Yes" input in this way, it feels clunky, plus there are a number of other code issues why this would be problematic.  I'm therefore looking for a way of fixing it in the voice interface.

My utterances for this intent do not contain the word "Yes" and I would never want this as a slot value either.

I appreciate that slot definitions only provide weightings for more likely matches, rather than defining enumerated lists, but is there any way I can specifically tell Alexa that a particular word should *never* be part of an utterance or slot?

Comment: Update: I have discovered that you can improve the likelihood of a different intent by adding utterances.  Specifically, you can add the utterance {YesIntent yes} to your voice interface and, surprisingly, that makes the YesIntent a more likely selection.